# Change behaviour of a custom command

Tags: pdftex

I have a custom command to itemize:

```
\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]{
    \item\small{#1\vspace{-2pt}}
}
```

How can I customize this command to change the label/ bullet type, say asterisk/ dash in different cases. Is it possible to pass the label type as the argument?

And if I have a given label type in the surrounding itemize command, which is again a custom one like the one below,can I change the bullet/ label type.

```
\newcommand{\CVItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]}
    \newcommand{\CVItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{2pt}}
```

Comment: `\small` doesn't take an argument  so your command would make all following text small not just text passed as an argument to your command. Is that intended?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \small can be removed,if we can add this another functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your list-like construction `\CVItemListStart`...`\CVItemListEnd` act like [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `label`-controlled environment in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[2][\defaultbullet]{%
  \item[#1] {\small #2\par}
}

\newcommand{\defaultbullet}{\textbullet}
\newcommand{\CVItemListStart}[1][\textbullet]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\defaultbullet}{#1}%
  \begin{itemize}[label=#1]}
\newcommand{\CVItemListEnd}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

First list:
\CVItemListStart
  \CVItem{First}
  \CVItem[$\ast$]{Second}
  \CVItem{Third}
  \CVItem[--]{Final}
\CVItemListEnd

Second list:
\CVItemListStart[$\ast$]
  \CVItem{First}
  \CVItem{Second}
  \CVItem{Third}
  \CVItem{Final}
\CVItemListEnd

Third list:
\CVItemListStart
  \CVItem{First}
  \CVItem{Second}
  \CVItem{Third}
  \CVItem{Final}
\CVItemListEnd

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to define a new command. The following code will do the job.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item [$\ast$] Point 1
    \item [$\bullet$] Point 2
\end{itemize}
```

Write the symbol you want to use for label/bullet type in square brackets after `\item`. It will do the job.

Comment: I don't want to mix them in one place, specifically I need to use say bullet   one side say top of the document and asterisk on the bottom.

Comment: @agarg Then why not `\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]` like in your original question?